# Consuming an authorized Web API from separate MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hey so the web API I have is using a custom forms authentication and the methods are authorized by role. Right now, I have a second separate MVC app that I wish to call a method of the Web API in, but obviously I can't because the app isn't authorized to access the data. The API itself works, because I tested it without the authorization.

I've been looking online and kind of found what I would need to do, but I can't piece all of the information together. Could someone be a huge help to me and just kind of layout the steps I need to take to get me started?

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: I've been following this code if it helps: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

```js
class Program {
  static void Main() {
    RunAsync().Wait();
  }

  static async Task RunAsync() {
    using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      // HTTP GET
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync < Product > ();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
      }
    }
  }
}
```